# Develop Python with something like RStudio

Tags: python, pycharm, ide, rstudio

I'm looking for an IDE that can act like RStudio to develop Python applications in. I love being able to execute code chunks ad-hoc just to see what they do, change it a bit, look at the output again, etc. However, I also want the structure that Pycharm brings, being able to open an entire repo as a project. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Rstudio is building in Python support:  https://rstudio.com/solutions/r-and-python/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just update you Rstudio , in the newest version of Rstudio , version 1.4 you can develop with python

[image: Check it here],

it installs a miniconda environment and then you can develop freely in python , in the environment Tab you will see that you will experience an ("R" like) experience of programming with Python .

Comment: Thanks. My life feels so much better now!

Comment: it feels great knowing that this helped you! I know how it feels once you get the ease of working in a specific IDE and that you wanna have the same experience in another language.

Answer (score 1):

I personally hate Jupyter Notebooks.  I'd recommend using Spyder, Pycharm, or VScode with extra emphasis on Spyder because it's python native and allows for remote connections for free (Pycharm is more sophisticated but you have to pay for the version that lets you connect to a remote kernel).

To execute a block of code in Spyder you just highlight what you want to run in the text editor and press f9.  Spyder has similar repo/ file management capabilities as Pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

Try Jupyter notebook, I think, it's what you want. Or you can run IPython notebooks in Pycharm e.g.